# Creating an NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

In the following code, the first log statement shows a decimal as expected, but the second logs NULL. What am I doing wrong?

```
NSDictionary *entry = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
  @"x", [NSNumber numberWithDouble:acceleration.x],
  @"y", [NSNumber numberWithDouble:acceleration.y],
  @"z", [NSNumber numberWithDouble:acceleration.z],
  @"date", [NSDate date],
  nil];
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [NSNumber numberWithDouble:acceleration.x]]);
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [entry objectForKey:@"x"]]);
```

Comment: On an unrelated note, the [NSString stringWithFormat:] bit is unnecessary, and potentially harmful. You should be calling NSLog like this: NSLog(@"%@", [entry objectForKey:@"x"]);. The first parameter to NSLog is a format string, which should just about always be a literal.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You are exchanging the order in which you insert objects and key: you need to insert first the object, then the key as shown in the following example.

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"value1", @"key1", @"value2", @"key2", nil];
```

Comment: If your values are being dynamically placed, pay extra attention if any values are null. This can make the creation of your dictionary stop in the middle, since `nil` is sentinel in method dispatch. Do a validation if needed. `NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"value1"?nil:@"", @"key1", @"value2"?nil:@"", @"key2", nil];`

Answer (score 23):

new Objective-c supports this new syntax for static initialisation.

```
@{key:value}
```

For example:

```
NSDictionary* dict = @{@"x":@(acceleration.x), @"y":@(acceleration.y), @"z":@(acceleration.z), @"date":[NSDate date]};
```

Comment: `[NSNumber numberWithDouble:acceleration.x]` can be written shorter too as `@(acceleration.x)`

Answer (score 6):

**NSDictionary Syntax:**

```
NSDictionary *dictionaryName = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"value1",@"key1",@value2",@"key2", nil];
```

**Example:**

```
NSDictionary *importantCapitals = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
@"NewDelhi",@"India",@"Tokyo",@"Japan",@"London",@"UnitedKingdom", nil];
NSLog(@"%@", importantCapitals);
```

Output looking like,

> {India = NewDelhi; Japan = Tokyo; UnitedKingdom = London; }