# Is there a 'trick' for sending raw NSString rather than NSData in a NSURLSession connection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdata, nsurlsession

I'm attempting to communicate with a backend using NSURLSession, however, the backend wasn't set up to properly read NSData, so it views the NSData login details I send over as false, I wanna know if its possible to get NSURLSession to send raw strings rather than NSData objects. I've looked in books and the webs and I've been stumped for weeks.

Redoing the backend is not an option, the engineer in charge of that left. Any help is welcome.

Thanks. Here's what I've done so far, in case anyone needs to see some code.

```
NSError *error;

NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration ];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];

NSString *rawUrlString = @"backend_url";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:rawUrlString];

NSLog(@"%@", url);


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            login data here

                            nil];

//NSLog(@"%@", parameters);

NSData *rawJson = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:rawJson encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSData *finalData = [myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

[body appendData:finalData];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"charset"];
[request setValue:@"XMLHttpRequest" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Requested-With"];

NSURLSessionDataTask *postTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
{
     NSLog(@"%@", [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil]);

}];

[postTask resume];
```

`

UPDATE: I've cleaned up the unnecessary bits this is the final code (still doesn't work though)

```
 NSError *error;

NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration ];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];

NSString *rawUrlString = @"backend_url";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:rawUrlString];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:login details nil];


NSData *rawJson = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:rawJson];

[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSURLSessionDataTask *postTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
{
     NSLog(@"%@", [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil]);

}];

[postTask resume];
```

Comment: At the lowest level you are just sending bytes to the server. Objects such as NSData and NSString are just higher level abstractions. What response are you getting back from the server?  Setting the Charset header to "application/json" looks wrong to me, as that is a mime type, not a Charset

Comment: Im getting an error telling me that the username and password fields are required

Comment: You're supplying parameters as JSON, but your header says that you intend to send `x-www-form-urlencoded`. Which is it? If JSON, your `Content-type` should change. If not JSON, then your `HTTPBody` should change.

Comment: brilliant Rob, Id give that a shot. Thanks

Comment: BTW, if you want to send JSON, you can just do `[request setHTTPBody:rawJson]` and get rid of the `myString`, `finalData`, and `body` variables, as all of that is redundant. This is not the immediate problem, but this can be simplified if you stay with JSON.

Comment: I just tried that and it still prompts the same error from the server, I also removed the unnecessary header field settings I included earlier (i initially put them on a trial-error basis).

Comment: Did you confirm if server is looking for JSON or `x-www-form-urlencoded` and change header or body as appropriate?

Comment: Ok, but other request fields are set wrong too. `application/json` is incorrect value for field `charset`. And the last one, why `XMLHttpRequest` when it should be JSON. :)

Comment: The server is looking for json and I've changed that to `[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];`

Comment: So maybe `parameters` dictionary is constructed in a wrong way? Are keys and values in proper order?

Comment: Yep I constructed it exactly as it is in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107996/creating-an-nsdictionary

Comment: @JoshuaAreogun The request looks basically correct, so the problem is likely that your server code and your client code are not in sync. You haven't shared how `login` is constructed, not precisely what the server is looking for. But the problem undoubtedly rests in a disconnect between the two of them.

Answer (score 2):

Your backend is setup to handle `NSData`. It's impossible to send a string over an internet connection, you can only send `NSData` and all servers expect it.

This code here is wrong:

```
NSData *rawJson = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:rawJson encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSData *finalData = [myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Instead just do this:

```
NSData *finalData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
```

The `NSData` object will contain a string in the correct format for the server to also recognise as a string. Note it will be in UTF-8 encoding, perhaps on some servers you will want to change that to something else.

Comment: What do you mean by "no luck"? Which line of code specifically doesn't work the way it should?

Comment: all of my code works. As I mentioned in the initial part of the question, i needed to know if there was a workaround to send the raw string as it seems there's a problem with the server side code which i have no access to. The server is still unable to decode the NSData info

Comment: @JoshuaAreogun NSData does not need to be decoded, it does not have any encoding of any kind. The problem is not `NSData`, it's something else you're doing wrong. Can you provide details from whoever runs the server how you are supposed to use it? Or some reference code in another language?