# Xcode - Objective C- How to make a dictionary of persons?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I can't get my head around my objective C code. I want to make a dictionary with persons that I save in the app. The dictionary is in first empty and then we need to add it from the textfields I created (see image)[textfieldWelkom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIAGZ.png)

For every person that is added, we have to show it in a list (see image) [lijstTabblad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lh1C4.png) in the tableviewcontroller. (The list has to be the whole name of the person)

I don't get the idea of how to making a dictionary with multiple persons with every person his own ELEMENTS. And how that I can get the elements again out of de dictionary for making the list etc..

(not like the 1 example but multiple values with that person)

I would be sow thankfull if you could help me!

Greetings,
Kevin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating an NSDictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107996/creating-an-nsdictionary)

Comment: You don't want a dictionary of multiple persons, you want a dictionary to represent each person, and then to collect those dictionaries in an array. Good luck

Comment: That is with 1 extra value. I need multiple values and I don't get it.. I don't get my head around..

Comment: Thx @Jef! It helps me a little

Answer (score 0):

- You needs to first create single person dictionary dictionary keys
  are like name sirname age and put values for respected keys
- add this dictionary in one array or another dictionary(array/dictionary must be mutable array)